# WPF combobox SelectedValue binding to string

Tags: wpf

I've bound my `ComboBox` `SelectedValue` to a `string` in my codebehind, but when the value is set, the string becomes a `ComboBoxItem`. How do I just bind the selected value as a string?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

This is probably because you have `ComboBoxItem` objects as items in your `ComboBox` and string is a content of each `ComobBoxItem`. So try setting `SelectedValuePath` to "Content" on your `ComboBox`:

```
<ComboBox SelectedValuePath="Content" .../>
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed!

Comment: Works in UWP too.